# Is there a reason no one uses an opamp when using the LM35 sensor?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

In most examples I've seen so far I've noticed that people connects directly the LM35 output to the Arduino's analog port. At room temp a reading from the sensor is 0.25V, which is 5% of total Arduino's analog range.

My question is if there is a good reason not to use an opamp so that the sensor's ouput spreads over the range 0..5V instead 0..1.5V. A good engineering practice is to spread the analog's input voltage as much as possible, but if no one is using it there should exist a reason.

Thanks!

Comment: Because the LM35 is _old_ technology. The device is still pretty good, however, but we've come up with a lot better devices. Ones that give a larger output range

Comment: Take the ATmega328 as an example, the ADC reference can be set to an internally provided 1.1V. That more or less gives what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the thing in general about analog to digital conversion, you generally want the scale of the value you read from the convertor to be a little wider than the expected normal range of the thing you want to measure so the granularity of the measurement is as fine as you can reasonably make it.

With a low value signal that means either amplifying the signal OR adjusting the reference range on the converter.

Here there is a trade off. The lower the level of the signal the more sensitive you are to ambient noise, both in the signal itself and in the reference voltage. Amplification on the other hand generally adds more components and new errors into the system.

Generally it is preferable to not mess with the signal any more than is absolutely necessary, but some design analysis is required to calculate which route provides you with the least amount of error.

The particular application, how much error matters, and amount of time you want to process the samples in code must also be factored in. Sometimes it is better to amplify and filter out noise in a pre-amplifier circuit, sometimes raw data is just fine.

There is no "one size fits all" answer to this question.

Comment: I found this nice white paper from TI. It doesn't answer my question, but gives some insight toward the using opamps: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt173/slyt173.pdf

Answer (score 0):

*moving my comment to an answer*

You could just change the **AREF** on the arduino to scale it up. **Also**, \$\frac{1024×0.25}{5}=51\$, and according to the datasheet it has \$\frac{10mv}{centigrade}\$. \$\frac{5}{1024}=4.8mv\$. So without any amplification you already have \$\frac{1}{2}\$ °C resolution. You usually don't need more than that. So if I read 51, I'm fairly certain that it's about 25.5 °C. **Also**, look at the output voltage in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf), it says -1V to 6V.

Comment: Under which circumstances one would get 6V at the output? The -1V to 6V range is marked as an absolute maximum rating. 6V would mean 600C which makes no sense. According to the maximum temperature, which is 150C, the maximum output voltage is 1.5V. This figure can be amplified 3 times in order to be close to the ADC's maximum input (in the case of Arduino at 5V).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why it says that when the max is 150 °C, but you can always go beyond the maximum settings, maybe it will give 6 volt at 180 °C without breaking, perhaps it becomes highly nonlinear. Either way, sure, go ahead, amplify it 3 times and get \$\frac{1}{6}\$ °C resolution. If you believe it's worth it.